# Communication between servers using Express and Request

Tags: node.js, express, post, server, request

Following scenario:
I got two servers, one server a Website, the other manages a database. The Website sends requests to its server, the request is passed to the backend server and a data set from the database should be returned.

I am using Express on both servers, the one serving the website also has the Request package.

Code on first server:

```
request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url:     'http://localhost:8081/getDataset',
        body:    "data="+data
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
            res.send(body)
        }
    }
)
```

Code on second server:

```
getFromEigenschaft (req, res) {
    var data = req.body.data
    console.log(req.body) //logs {}

    //do database stuff with data
    return res.status(200).send(dataSet)

}
```

On the second server req.body is an empty object though. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
The body object can be set to a JSON, just as I want to, but the JSON option must be set to true:

```
request.post({
        headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url:     'http://localhost:8081/getDataset',
        json:   true,
        body:    data
    },
    function(error, response, body){
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
            res.send(body)
        }
    }
)
```